# Why can't i reach the variable i inside the listener function?

Tags: javascript

why can't i use the variable i inside the listener function ?

```js
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
  const newElement = document.createElement('p');
  newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;

  newElement.addEventListener('click', function respondToTheClick(evt) {
    console.log('A paragraph was clicked.'+i);
  });

  myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```

Comment: Tested it in firefox, and it is working. Maybe your problem is a result of some other code on your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works for me, check that your question is correct.

```js
const myCustomDiv = document.createElement('div');

for (let i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
    const newElement = document.createElement('p');
    newElement.textContent = 'This is paragraph number ' + i;

    newElement.addEventListener('click', function respondToTheClick(evt) {
        console.log('A paragraph was clicked.'+i);
        console.log(`the counter at this time was: ${i}`)
    });

    myCustomDiv.appendChild(newElement);
}

document.body.appendChild(myCustomDiv);
```